# App update, only uninstall button and no more icon or open button in playstore

Tags: android

I wanted to go from normal Android project (from 2015) to Gradle project and so I did everything needed.. the manifest is the same and everything seems to work but when I did the update on the store, my app completely disappeared off my phone, no more icon and in the playstore I have only the option to uninstall it..

Did someone get this kind of issue? 
I tried everything even using activity-alias to be sure it's the same package name and activity.. but does not seem to fix the issue

Comment: you liklely have a problem with main/launcher activity in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

remove this from the splash screen

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data
      android:host="example.page.link"
      android:scheme="https" />
```

if you have used it inside intent-filter of the splash screen.
And if it is not possible, use another intent-filter inside splash screen
like,

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="example.page.link"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```